# "There was some attempts" or "there were some attempts"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is

Is the grammar in the following Alice in Wonderland quote correct? Would it be more appropriate to use *were* given that the noun phrase is plural?

> There was some attempts at applause, which was immediately suppressed by the officers of the court,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typographical error in the OP's source material.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a simple [error](http://books.google.com/books?id=lSQqv7R7S2sC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22at+applause,+which+was+immediately+suppressed+by+the+officers+of+the+court%22&source=bl&ots=hp_tqgxOYY&sig=x9UsGPeoQkOhpe3O7jzCseXAmro&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0YXkUvbcDIfnsATvyIDwCw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22at%20applause%2C%20which%20was%20immediately%20suppressed%20by%20the%20officers%20of%20the%20court%22&f=false). A search of google books has the quote as, “There was some attempt at applause, which was immediately suppressed by the officers of the court."

Scanning books can result in errors which get perpetuated when copied from one site to another.

Comment: It wasn't a scanning error … Google books has a 1941 edition with the error, and a 1869 edition without the error. It was probably a  error introduced in typesetting, but it's still clearly an error.

Comment: @ Peter Shor.  I believe you meant to say _an error_.

Answer (score 0):

*Some* is both a pronoun and an adjective (and occasionally an adverb).

In some instances, it has a plural connotation and in others, singular

> *There are some who think we are evil.*
>
> *There is some difficulty with this sentence.*

In general, the pronominal usage is plural. The adjectival usage is governed by the number of the noun or pronoun modified.

> *There is some question about this post.*
>
> *There are some questions about this post.*

In a strict sense, Mr. Carroll has mixed a singular predicate nominative (*attempts*) with a singular verb (*was*), a prescriptive no-no. The adjective *some* has little to do with the number agreement in this case.  And Mr. Carroll should surely take grammatical advice from me.

Comment: _Some_ is a **quantifier**. Quantifiers are not in the 5th-century list of The Eight Parts of Speech. Quantifiers were discovered in the 20th century, not the Fifth.

Comment: This was a **typo**. It needs no justification.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is there no value in attending to distinction between a quantifier that stands alone and one that modifies some other form? Why can't it be a quantifier *and* an pronoun or adjective?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Quantifiers *per se* were used in the Aristotelian syllogism system; whenever you consider that was codified, it was before the fifth century.

Comment: But they were codified only in the square of opposition, as varieties of proposition; there was no proper functional codification. Anyway, the point is that the head noun, whether it's present or not, is what governs number agreement. If you don't know what the head noun is sposta be, you don't understand the sentence and can't answer the question.